# Merit list in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to sort my mysql table depending on four columns cet score,graduation marks,12th marks and then 10th marks. First cet marks will be considered if they r equal then graduation marks and so on... How can I do it?

```
Sr-no       cet    graduation.    class12    class10

1             100    450.           440.          540
2.            100    530            430.          540
3             98.    450.           432.          533
4.            98.    450            440.          460
```

Result will be

```
Sr-no         cet graduation 12   10 

2            100   530       430.  540 
1            100.  450.      440.  540
4            98.   450.      440.  460
3.           98.   450.      432.  533
```

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result. (As formatted text.)

Comment: Please, not as a comment. Edit the question instead!

Answer (score 0):

Order by will work..and if you place all columns(as in your question), each one will act as tie breaker in the order they were introduced

Nulls will change the whole equation (if they are present )

Pseudo query

```
Order by 
cet score,graduation marks,12th marks , 10th marks
```

Comment: ok you may want to post your data as suggested in comments above

Comment: Thnx dude. I tried it again but this Time I used desc for order by and it given me the exact result.